# Odd result From DecimalFormat Rounding Half Up

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

Supplying a float value of `37.35` I am getting a string of `37.3`

Here is my code.

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat(".0");
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
return format.format(37.35f);
```

I would expect to receive a string of `37.4`. What am I doing wrong?

I think it may be due to passing a float in however I don't have a choice as to the type of variable I receive. Even if the actual representation of the `float` was `37.3500221215051544` it should still be rounded up?

The whole point of formatting this value to a string is so I can pass it to `BigDecimal` and have exact values such as `37.4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

37.35 actually closer to 37.3 then to 37.4. You can check it woth following code:

```
System.out.println(37.35f-37.3f);
System.out.println(37.4f-37.35f);
```

in prints `0.049999237` and `0.05000305`.

With `double` data type the result is differrent.

To solve this problem just add a little delta to your numbers. For exapmle, 0.01.

Comment: Please u must use BigDecimal class in Java! It´s has a method to round up and get the format u want like String, double, etc. And the most important thing, you dont loose precision using this class!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the precision of float datatype in the Floating Point Arithmetic of computer. As @Zefick shows in his answer, the representation of 37.35 like float is actually closer to 37.3 than to 37.4; because it is slightly less than 37.35.

The use of double precision solves the problem, but being this a restriction I suggest using a wrapper:

```
    return format.format(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(37.35f)));
```